# how to transform the combining Z score (Zi=Φ−1(1−pi/2)) to adjusted P value in weighted Stouffer's approach?

Tags: meta-analysis

we perform a two-tailed two sample t test in each dataset and obtained P values. then we use weighted stouffer's Z score method to transform each Pi to Zi (Zi=Φ−1(1−pi/2)) and the combining Z [image].
Now, I don't know how to transform the combining Z score to stouffer's adjusted P value, whether P'=2Φ(Z) or P'=Φ(Z) ?

Comment: It is unusual to use two-sided values as the input as it means that studies with completely different conclusions are treated as giving the same results. Can you clarify why you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I use a two-tailed t test between A and B, because I  don't know whose mean value is larger beforehand. I want to know if there is any difference between A and B, so the null hypothesis is mean(A)=mean(B).  Both mean(A)>mean(B) and mean(A)<mean(B) can be accepted. @mdewey

Comment: So if one study says men are taller than women and one says women are taller than men what conclusion will your meta-analysis come to?

Comment: It depends on the formula of the combining Z value. The conclusion is mostly draw from the smaller Pi and larger ωi. Note that, if Ti statistics is negative  corresponding to Pi, the Zi is negative. otherwise not.  I don't know if I made it clear. @mdewey

Comment: I understand that. My question was whether that corresponded to your scientific question.